# What does "from connected to" exactly mean?

Tags: meaning

> **From connected to cloud,** this scanner series is easy to setup and
>   integrate with any environment.

It seems something is omitted here. Does it mean "this scanner series which is connected to cloud" or "this scanner series which has a function to connect to cloud"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, ***connected*** is acting as a noun, but a noun for a category. You can think of it as being attached to **environment**. It might be rephrased as

> "In any environment, from connected to cloud, this scanner series is easy to setup and integrate."

That's not perfectly synonymous as it misses some nuance, but it makes the grammar clearer. *Connected* and *cloud* are both adjectives, sharing the same implicit noun to allow them each to function as noun phrases.

Given the proximity to *cloud*, it may be a reference to *connected computing*.

Answer (score 0):

A range of possibilities, can be expressed as "from (beginning of range) to (end of range)" From hot to cold. From small to large. From young to old. From rich to poor. From near to far. "From connected to cloud" represents a range of possibilities for using the scanner. "Connected" directly to a PC is considered by the writer of that text to be at one end of the range, and to be shared by multiple users in some kind of "cloud" arrangement is at the other. These, and whatever possibilities that are in between them are ways of using the scanner.